# Public IP from my ISP

Tags: networking, router, ip-address

I have dynamic ip address from my ISP and today I bought public ip from them. My question is: Do I need something from them to have this public ip? Do I need to configure anything on my router?

Comment: It should happen automatically ... but it wouldn't hurt to power cycle your router - which will force it to pick up a new IP adress. You can then check to make sure it is different from your old dynamic IP address. If in doubt call your ISP ;)

Comment: Usually, yes, you'll set the Public IP as the IP of one of the interfaces on the router. In some cases though, the Public IP will simply be the DHCP IP your router gets from the ISP, in which case you only have to restart the router (or release/renew DHCP lease) to have this new IP.

Comment: Under WAN tab in my router I still have the same ip private address like before. I restarted my router several times.

Comment: Go [here](http://www.whatsmyip.org/) and you will see what is your IP address as seen by others in the Internet.

Comment: The address from these sites is exactly the same when I didn't buy public ip. What is more when I forward any port in my router and add exception in my Windows firewall every progoram I use says that all the ports are not opened

Comment: You really need to talk to your ISP.  You may need to to configure a static IP manually, but only they can tell you what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your specific ISP, in some cases your current dynamic IP will simply get stuck to your account, so you will not need to do anything for it to remain static and public.

In other cases, you will be assigned a new IP after your router releases its current IP and requests a new one.

If you are unsure, the best way to go is to contact your ISP, however a normal router reset should do the trick.

What you do with the new IP is a different matter, but to test that my new IP is public what I would do is set up a webserver (nginx or apache) and visit my public IP from a Tor connected browser. To do this you might need to [forward a port](http://portforward.com/networking/staticip.htm) from your router to the machine where you have the webserver. Forwarding a port is done at the router interface which you can usually reach by browsing to `192.168.0.1` (YMMV). And installing a webserver depends on your operating system (in linux you can do `sudo apt-get install nginx` and thats it). [Installing the Tor bundle](https://www.torproject.org/download/download) is fairly easy.

Comment: I always couldn't forward any port. I checked if they are opened by various programs and they all are closed. I installed xampp and started apache. I got my ip address from sites like whatismyip and i put it in tor browser. No connection

Comment: Try to reach your web server from your local computer (without Tor), if you can reach the site then we can move on to the port forwarding issue. For that screenshots will be useful, or post the exact model of your router and the internal IP that you're trying to map

Comment: I can reach the site with localhost and local ip: 192.168.1.104. My router model is TP-LINK TL-WR340G. I reserved my local ip address under 'address reservation' tab [link](http://i.imgur.com/YrUMODR.png). Under 'virtual servers' tab I forwarded port 80 to my local ip [link](http://i.imgur.com/gsuunPD.png). It's probably not case of a computer because I had such issues on my previous one.